# Run-time Error, Library not registered with macro importing attachments from outlook subfolders

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I have the following code which I believe should work to save attachments from an Outlook subfolder to the specified path, before emptying the subfolder.

```
 Sub Downloadattachments()

 Dim applOutlook As Outlook.Application
 Dim ns As Namespace
 Dim inbox As MAPIFolder
 Dim item As Object
 Dim atmt As Attachment
 Dim FileName As String
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim SubFolder As MAPIFolder
 Dim SubSubFolder As MAPIFolder
 Dim VariableName As Name

 Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
 Set SubFolder = inbox.Folders("Paul")
 Set SubSubFolder = SubFolder.Folders("Soja")
 i = 0

 If SubSubFolder.Items.Count = 0 Then
 MsgBox
 Else: End If
 If SubSubFolder.Items.Count > 0 Then
For Each item In SubSubFolder.Items
For Each atmt In item.attachments
    FileName = "\\homefolder5\bases" & atmt.FileName
    atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
i = i + 1
item.Delete
Next atmt
 Next item
 End If

 End Sub
```

Unfortunately I don't get past the line `Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")` before encountering the run-time error stating "Automation error: Library not registered". To clarify, I have the Microsoft Outlook 14.0 Object Library activated, along with other basic libraries. I think this must be something different.

I apologize if this is a really simple thing that I am overlooking, but I would appreciate whatever guidance you could give me!

Answer (score 0):

Where do you run the VBA macro?

```
Dim applOutlook As Outlook.Application
```

It looks like you didn't initialize the applOutlook object in the code. If you develop an Outlook VBA macro, you can use the Application property:

```
Set applOutlook = Application
Set ns = applOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
```

In case if you automate Outlook you need to create a new instance of the Application class. See [How to automate Outlook from another program](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/kb/201096?wa=wsignin1.0) for more information.